# ng-if not working with ng-disbaled in angular js

Tags: angularjs

i want to create button if `msg_id == 1` but it should be disabled if `msg_id == 1` and `level == false`

Here is how i am doing

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" ng-if="msg_id == 1" ng-disabled="msg_id == 1 && level == false">Click</a>
```

but it's not disabling link.

how can i disable this link in above scenario?

Comment: `a` tag don't have disbabled property.

Comment: you can check for the disabled attribute in css `a["disabled"] { pointer-events: none }`

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi what about button